# question about partitions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Im trying to solve the following exercise. Im including a definition.

[image]

My attempt:

Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be a partition of $\Omega$ such that $\mathcal{Q}$ refines both $\mathcal{P}_i $ for $i=1,2$. So by definition, if we take arbitrary $A \in \mathcal{Q}$, then can write

$$ A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} E_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^m F_j $$

Where $E_i \in \mathcal{P}_1, \; \; F_j \in \mathcal{P}_2 $.

$$ \therefore A = A\cap A = \bigcup_{i,j}(E_i \cap F_j)$$

Since $E_i, F_j$ partition $A$ by hypothesis, then $A$ is a disjoint union of the intersecition of the $E's$ and $F's$. So, $\mathcal{Q} $ refines the partition $\mathcal{R} = \{ E \cap F : E \in \mathcal{P}_1 \; \; and \; \; F \in \mathcal{P}_2 \} $. This is a partition since by argument above, can take $A = \Omega$. and this $\mathcal{R}$ refines each $\mathcal{P}_i$. MY question is: How can we show this is the coarsest partition?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have it backward.  To say that $\mathcal{Q}$ refines (is a refinement of) $\mathcal{P}$ means that every set in  $\mathcal{P}$ is a union of sets in $\mathcal{Q}$, not vice versa.

By the way, the definition of "coarsest partition which refines them both" in the question is not the usual one, although it turns out to work for the purposes of this problem.  Usually "$\mathcal{P}$ is coarser than $\mathcal{Q}$" means "$\mathcal{Q}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{P}$," not "$\mathcal{P}$ has fewer sets than $\mathcal{Q}$."

In any case, what you should prove is that if $\mathcal{P}$ is the partition consisting of nonempty intersections $A \cap B$ with $A \in \mathcal{P}_1$ and $B \in \mathcal{P}_2$, then

1. $\mathcal{P}$ refines both $\mathcal{P}_1$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$, and
2. If $\mathcal{Q}$ is a partition refining both $\mathcal{P}_1$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$, then $\mathcal{Q}$ refines $\mathcal{P}$.